# Changing folder security permissions via Win32 API

Tags: c++, security, winapi

My C++ application stores some common user data in `%CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA%\Company\Product`. I want to make sure the Users group has write permissions to this folder which on Vista it does not.  How would do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out myself using ATL...

```
CDacl oDacl;
AtlGetDacl(strFolder, SE_FILE_OBJECT, &oDacl);
oDacl.RemoveAces(Sids::Users()); // Remove existing "Users" access
oDacl.AddAllowedAce(Sids::Users(), FILE_ALL_ACCESS, CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE | OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE);
AtlSetDacl(strFolder, SE_FILE_OBJECT, oDacl);
```

Of course my real code contains error checking.